# Video converter on Windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, video-processing

I want to make a video converter for windows phone. But I could not find a library to use for such purpose. I made the same on linux and windows 7 os using ffmpeg. But how can I do that for a windows phone 7? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it is possible as i could not find anything in terms of APIs in the public SDK.